# Woff open-type fonts not working in local?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have downloaded a .Woff font (Ubuntu), here is the code related to it:

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff) format('woff');
}
```

I downloaded it and put it directly into my css folder.

I canged the src value to:

```
src: local('Ubuntu'), url(ubuntu.woff) format('woff');
```

(I renamed my font to Ubuntu.woff)
But the font is not working with the local URL, I checked the path Chrome gives me(can't find font located at whatever/whatever/css/Ubuntu.woff) and it's the right path. Anyone has an idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find some Woff to TTF converter on the Internet, fixing the issue this way was a great alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing with another .woff Google web font, but on Windows.
Apparently windows said the file format was not valid.

Comment: I am on Windows too. I tried setting up the "Ubuntu.woff" font, so I can use the Linux Ubuntu's font on Windows ^^.